# Count Query required

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, datetime, time

```
ID          Time                    Status
----------- ----------------------- --------------------------------------------------
1           2013-12-24 00:00:00     on
2           2013-12-25 00:00:00     on
3           2013-12-26 00:00:00     on
4           2013-12-27 00:00:00     on
5           2013-12-28 00:00:00     on
6           2013-12-29 00:00:00     on
7           2013-12-30 00:00:00     on
8           2013-12-31 00:00:00     on
9           2013-12-24 00:00:00     off
10          2013-12-25 00:00:00     off
11          2013-12-27 00:00:00     off
12          2013-12-27 00:00:00     on
13          2013-12-27 00:00:00     off
14          2013-12-27 00:00:00     on
15          2013-12-27 00:00:00     off
16          2013-12-28 00:00:00     on
17          2013-12-28 00:00:00     off
18          2013-12-28 00:00:00     on
19          2013-12-29 00:00:00     off
20          2013-12-29 00:00:00     on
21          2013-12-30 00:00:00     off
22          2013-12-30 00:00:00     on
23          2013-12-30 00:00:00     off
24          2013-12-30 00:00:00     on
25          2013-12-30 00:00:00     off
26          2013-12-31 00:00:00     on
27          2013-12-31 00:00:00     off
28          2013-12-31 00:00:00     on
29          2013-12-31 00:00:00     off
30          2013-12-31 00:00:00     on
31          2013-12-31 00:00:00     off
```

I have this Data , I want a query that categorized them by Date and by on and Off

with column names Date , On , Off , I am using Microsoft SQL server 2008

Comment: So write a query that does it

Answer (score 1):

Lets say the column containing date was named `yourDateColumn` and the column containing status was named `statusColumn`, you could do:

```
SELECT yourDateColumn, 
 SUM(statusColumn="On") as On, 
 SUM(statusColumn="Off") as Off 
 FROM yourTable 
 GROUP BY yourDateColumn
 ORDER BY yourDateColumn
```

Comment: Please dont trust anymore on implicit GROUP BY sorting, this is official deprecated as off MySQL version 5.6

Comment: Sorting? That was not discussed in the question. Didn't mean to imply that it will implicitly sort too

Comment: As sidenotes: MySQL is always using an sorting when you are using GROUP BY... if you dont need that "feature" disable that extra "overhead (using filesort in explain)" with `ORDER BY NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the name or structure of your table but from the data i was able to figure out this should work.

```
SELECT Date, SUM(status="On") as On_count, SUM(status="Off") as Off_count 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Date 
Order by Date;
```

Comment: Please dont trust anymore on implicit GROUP BY sorting, this is official deprecated as off MySQL version 5.6

Comment: Thank you. haven't been reading much these days more coding.

Comment: Does ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY work well?

Comment: sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is an different isseu what is complety out off the scope... You should always use an explicit ORDER BY ... when using GROUP BY ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.Time, Count(t_on.id),Count(t_off.id) FROM Table1 t
LEFT JOIN Table1 t_on
ON t.id= t_on.id and t_on.Status = 'on'
LEFT JOIN Table1 t_off
ON t.id= t_off.id and t_off.Status = 'off'
GROUP BY t.Time Order by Time;
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96c63/7)**

Comment: I am getting this error

Comment: I am getting this error , I am Using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: U tagged mysql for fun?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '='.I am getting this Error as I am using SQl Server 2008

Comment: Sorry , its my first post , I will not repeat this mistake again

Comment: see the edits and fiddle

Comment: That should indeed work