# Count Query Required in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, datetime, count

```
ID          Time                    Status
----------- ----------------------- --------------------------------------------------
1           2013-12-24 00:00:00     on
2           2013-12-25 00:00:00     on
3           2013-12-26 00:00:00     on
4           2013-12-27 00:00:00     on
5           2013-12-28 00:00:00     on
6           2013-12-29 00:00:00     on
7           2013-12-30 00:00:00     on
8           2013-12-31 00:00:00     on
9           2013-12-24 00:00:00     off
10          2013-12-25 00:00:00     off
11          2013-12-27 00:00:00     off
12          2013-12-27 00:00:00     on
13          2013-12-27 00:00:00     off
14          2013-12-27 00:00:00     on
15          2013-12-27 00:00:00     off
16          2013-12-28 00:00:00     on
17          2013-12-28 00:00:00     off
18          2013-12-28 00:00:00     on
19          2013-12-29 00:00:00     off
20          2013-12-29 00:00:00     on
21          2013-12-30 00:00:00     off
22          2013-12-30 00:00:00     on
23          2013-12-30 00:00:00     off
24          2013-12-30 00:00:00     on
25          2013-12-30 00:00:00     off
26          2013-12-31 00:00:00     on
27          2013-12-31 00:00:00     off
28          2013-12-31 00:00:00     on
29          2013-12-31 00:00:00     off
30          2013-12-31 00:00:00     on
31          2013-12-31 00:00:00     off
```

My table name is `abc` and I want to arrange data datewise and status wise with counts of on and counts of off datewise

Comment: please don't cross post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764358/count-query-required/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select time, SUM(on_cnt),SUM(off_cnt) FROM
(select time,[on] as on_cnt,[off] as off_cnt from table1
pivot 
(
 count(Status)
 for Status in ([on],[off])
) as p) as st
GROUP BY time
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96c63/34)**

Comment: Perfectly working , but it is using 3 joins , is not any way to minimize the number of joins  ?

Comment: check now. Eliminated join

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
SELECT 
[Time], 
SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'On' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CntON,
SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'Off' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) CntOff
FROM Table
GROUP BY [Time]
```

Comment: it is good and working , but its repeating the date like

Comment: It will only repeat the date if it has a time part too, from your example it does not. So does it have a time part?

Comment: ok , I understand , yes it has different time , you are right

Comment: and how can I remove the time part ?

Comment: CAST it to DATE. So something like `CAST([Time] AS Date) DateOnly`